# When searching Youtube using the Data API, how can I exclude videos that cannot be played externally?

Tags: search, embedded-resource, youtube-api

The Youtube API will return videos that can be played no problem within the chromeless player. It also returns videos that cannot be played, - "Embedding disabled by request".

I don't want to retrieve videos that cannot be played, is there a way to request only videos that can be embedded?

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a parameter exactly for this purpose. In this Url

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=connemara&orderby=published&max-results=10&v=2&format=5

the "format=5" parameter restricts the results to **embeddable** videos. See the '[Developer's Guide: Data API Protocol – API Query Parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html)'.

Comment: Hi, I am using the below api to get some videos of youtube:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/charts/movies/trending?v=2&paid-content=false&hl=en&alt=json&format=5
But, I am getting some videos that can not be embed ..as you can see the embed = 'denied' in results.. so what to do now ?