# Exclude all videos in youtube api playlist which says "The video is not available"

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am using the foloowing api for fetching the playlist of youtube channel:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=*********************&playlistId=PLtS_xRaINoXVqR9JTzwkcMLaOIq0uj831&part=snippet,contentDetails&format=6&maxResults=50&fields=items

some of the videos is not available so how can i exclude those videos ?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187398/when-searching-youtube-using-the-data-api-how-can-i-exclude-videos-that-cannot

Comment: It did not work for me :(

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001251/youtube-v3-api-know-if-the-video-is-avaliable-on-android-mobile-device) if it can help you:)

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos) by including a region (where you are) you can avoid "not available in your region" errors.

```
 &regionCode=es
```

Changing the format type to 5 (API v2) or checking `status.Embeddablè` (API v3) will avoid those videos where embedding is disabled.

Other causes are when the Video is recently uploaded. In this case you should first do a check with the [Video Status API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_checking_video_status)